# Can anyone show me to a skeletal mono codebase just to get me started?

Tags: mono

Maybe this is a poor question, but, I can't find a tutorial or even a bare codebase for mono.  I'd really like to start using it quickly.

--EDIT--

This isn't such a poor question after all.  By asking it, the terms "skeletal mono codebase" actually help out now, whereas before, obviously, I had to ask.  I love StackEx so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at these, [MonkeyGuide](http://www.mono-project.com/Monkeyguide), [Mono Wiki](http://mono.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3aTutorials) and using [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/Documentation/Creating_A_Simple_Solution)